# Can't boot to windows after ubuntu install

Tags: dual-boot, windows, uefi, boot-repair

I've installed ubuntu, but now i can't boot to windows. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7022020/) is my boot repair output.

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: @JohnnyD. [That technique](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) may be necessary to get Ubuntu to boot after someone applies [your solution](http://askubuntu.com/a/428489/22949), though. (So you might want to mention it in your answer.)

Answer (score 1):

try this solution:

First boot on your Windows installation DVD and navigate to the section `repair your computer`if it finds your Windows installation, make sure it is `unselected` before clicking next, then click on `Command prompt` and run:

```
bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /fixmbr
```

then reboot and remove your installation DVD

if you don't have the installation DVD you can get Windows [repair disk](http://forums.techarena.in/guides-tutorials/1114725.htm) (Win7 example) manually created.

Just in case if after all facing any issues yet check on [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: This solution might work for a problem with similar symptoms in a BIOS-only installation, but it won't help in this case, because the problem is with a mixed BIOS/EFI installation. There's no evidence of a problem with the Windows boot loader per se; and even if there is such a problem, the more fundamental issue will have to be addressed first.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a mixed-mode (BIOS/EFI) installation: Windows is installed in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode on `/dev/sdb` and Ubuntu is installed in EFI/UEFI mode on `/dev/sda`. (Most such mixed-mode installations go the other way around.) Getting dual-boot working with OSes installed in differing modes is awkward at best and impossible at worst.

Given that Windows is less flexible that Linux on this score, my recommendation is to install a BIOS-mode version of GRUB for Linux. Try it this way:

1. Boot to Linux.
2. Using GParted, `parted`, or `gdisk`, create a ~1MiB partition at the very end of the disk. If you use GParted or `parted`, give it a `bios_grub` flag. If you use `gdisk`, give it a type code of EF02. It's possible that GParted and/or `parted` will balk at creating such a small partition, but `gdisk` will definitely do it.
3. Reboot to a Linux live CD. Boot *in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.* This can usually be achieved by selecting a boot option in the firmware's built-in boot manager that *lacks* the string "EFI" or "UEFI." Unfortunately, the exact procedures vary greatly from one computer to another, so you may need to experiment or ask for more help on this point.
4. Run Boot Repair again and tell it to re-install GRUB.

At this point, you should be able to boot into both Linux and Windows in BIOS mode, with GRUB controlling the boot process. You might need to fiddle with your boot options to get a BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode boot to work as the default, though.

Unfortunately, some EFIs have bugs that can complicate matters with BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode booting from GPT disks. Check [this Web page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/bios.html) if you have problems getting GRUB to come up in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode. In a worst-case scenario, you might need to convert `/dev/sda` from GPT to MBR.

The alternative to this is to convert Windows to boot in EFI mode. This will require converting `/dev/sdb` from MBR to GPT and installing an EFI-mode Windows boot loader. This process is described [here,](https://gitorious.org/tianocore_uefi_duet_builds/pages/Windows_x64_BIOS_to_UEFI) in case you want to pursue it.