# Installed Ubuntu, can't boot into Windows 10

Tags: dual-boot, boot-repair, windows-10

http://paste.ubuntu.com/15919501/

I'm not exactly sure how to boot into windows 10 again.

Comment: This post might be duplicated. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/727528/dual-boot-win10-xubuntu-install-cant-find-windows?rq=1
and http://askubuntu.com/questions/428385/cant-boot-to-windows-after-ubuntu-install?rq=1

Comment: You have grub in sda, and Windows boot loader on sdb. But better to have each system's boot loader on same drive as install. And often better to have Windows as sda. Do not use Boot-Repair's auto fix as that installs grub to both drives. Use advanced mode and install Windows type boot loader to sda and grub to sdb. Set BIOS to boot sdb. If Windows not found or will not boot directly from booting sda, then you have Windows issues. Perhaps left fast start up or hibernation on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There are some disk read/write errors. Please check the disk for any
  errors.
- Apart from this make sure that your BIOS points to the device where
  /boot is being created.

Answer (score 0):

I used the boot-repair software with the advanced options, and was able to boot into windows 10. Also I converted my windows install from legacy MBR to UEFI. This made it a lot easier to create a dual boot installation of ubuntu.